# How do I make Conjugate behave more consistently?

Tags: complex, built-in-symbols

Sometimes `Conjugate` distributes.  Sometimes it doesn't.  Look:

```
Conjugate[a b]
(* Conjugate[a b] *)

Conjugate[2 a b]
(* 2 Conjugate[a b] *)   (*'2' pulled out*)

Conjugate[a (b + c)]
(* Conjugate[a (b + c)] *)

Conjugate[a (b + 2 c)]
(* Conjugate[a] (Conjugate[b] + 2 Conjugate[c]) *)  (* Distributed! *)

Conjugate[a (b + c (d + e))]
(* Conjugate[a (b + c (d + e))] *)
```

1. Why is `Conjugate` behaving like this (that is, *inconsistently*)?
2. Is there a switch I can toggle that prevents `Conjugate` from doing stuff willy nilly?  I don't mind if `Conjugate[2 a b]` stays `Conjugate[2 a b]`.  It's more consistent that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = {a b, 2 a b, a (b + c), a (b + 2 c), a (b + c (d + e))};
```

If you never want [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate.html) to distribute, use [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html)

```
Inactive[Conjugate] /@ list
```

[image]

If you want `Conjugate` to always distribute

```
conj[expr_] := 
 ComplexExpand[expr, Variables@Level[expr, {-1}], 
   TargetFunctions -> Conjugate] // Simplify

conj@*Conjugate /@ list

(*  {Conjugate[a] Conjugate[b], 2 Conjugate[a] Conjugate[b], 
 Conjugate[a] (Conjugate[b] + Conjugate[c]), 
 Conjugate[a] (Conjugate[b] + 2 Conjugate[c]), 
 Conjugate[a] (Conjugate[b] + Conjugate[c] (Conjugate[d] + Conjugate[e]))}  *)
```

If any variables are Reals, say `a` and `c`, then use [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html)

```
Simplify[%, Element[{a, c}, Reals]]

(*  {a Conjugate[b], 2 a Conjugate[b], a (c + Conjugate[b]), 
 a (2 c + Conjugate[b]), a (Conjugate[b] + c (Conjugate[d] + Conjugate[e]))}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica does not know the nature of your symbols. It knows for sure that 2 is a real number - so it can use proper distribution. You can always specify your variables to get a more consistent answer. For example,

```
Simplify[Conjugate[a (b + c)], Assumptions -> {a, b, c} ∈ Reals]
```

> a (b + c)

```
Simplify[Conjugate[a (b + c)], Assumptions -> {{a, b} ∈ Reals}]
```

> a (b + Conjugate[c])

```
Simplify[Conjugate[a (b + c)], Assumptions -> {{a} ∈ Reals}]
```

> a Conjugate[b + c]

Or you can use `Expand` as well to see all the terms distinctly

```
Expand[Simplify[Conjugate[a (b + c)], Assumptions -> {a, b, c} ∈ Reals]]
```

> a b + a c

And last but not the least, the most general case

```
Simplify[Conjugate[a (b + c)], Assumptions -> {a, b, c} ∈ Complexes]
```

> Conjugate[a (b + c)]

Comment: This is fine, do you know how to keep the whole expression together inside `Conjugate`?  I don't like it behaves in my fourth example.  Notice also `Conjugate[a (b + c (d + 2 e))]` *doesn't* expand, despite there being a `2` inside.

Comment: You can define your variables as `Complexes` (I put it at the end of my answer). In `Conjugate[a (b + c (d + 2 e))]`, `2e` is again multiplied by `c` and then `a` which puzzles MMA :)