# Make ConjugateTranspose distributive

Tags: symbolic, complex

Related to [123974](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123974), is there a way to make the `ConjugateTranspose` function, input as `esc-hc-esc` distributive for all symbols? For example, with `d = (a + b)/Sqrt[2]`, I want `d\[HermitianConjugate]` give $(a^\dagger+b^\dagger)/\sqrt{2}$. I can define

```
hc[x__Plus] := Plus @@ (ConjugateTranspose /@ (List @@ x))
```

which only takes care of terms like `hc[a+b]` bit not for more complicated expressions.

Comment: Have you looked at `Distribute`?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit yes, `Distribute` works for e.g. `a+b` but not, say, `(a+b)/2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this work for you?

```
ConjugateTranspose[d] //. {
  ConjugateTranspose[(op : (Plus | Times))[a__]] :> op @@ (ConjugateTranspose /@ {a}),
  ConjugateTranspose[NonCommutativeMultiply[a__]] :> NonCommutativeMultiply @@ (ConjugateTranspose /@ Reverse[{a}]),
  ConjugateTranspose[n_?NumericQ] :> Conjugate[n]
  }
```

Essentially, this uses `ReplaceRepeated` to implement the algebraic rules of `ConjugateTranspose`: it falls through addition and (scalar) multiplication; it turns numbers into their conjugates; and it falls through non-commutative multiplication but reverses the order of multiplication.

Comment: works for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: also added rule: `ConjugateTranspose[ConjugateTranspose[a__]] :> a` so that $(a^\dagger)^\dagger=a$.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't do that by itself? Well, seems sensible to me, then. I would change the matching pattern to `ConjugateTranspose[ConjugateTranspose[a_]]`, though, since `ConjugateTranspose` should never have more than one argument in the first place.

Comment: good, point, thanks again!